# Непонятный баг в ACF Pro, wordpress. Не отображаются картинки из ГАЛЕРЕИ

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка.
Я использую плагин ACF pro для добавления кастомный полей. Создал 2 ГРУППЫ gallery1 и gallery2 (название поля) и в каждой из этих груп есть поле Галерея (card_gallery), также в этих группах есть ещё поля текста и цвета. Группы отличаются только названием всё остальное одинаковое. И проблемма в том, что при выводе url адреса картинки -- gallery1 вываёт url, а gallery2 пустой.

```php
<?php $one = get_field('gallery1') ?>
<?php $two = get_field('gallery2') ?>
            
<?php $three = $one['card_gallery'] ?>
<?php $fore = $two['card_gallery'] ?>

<?php echo $three[0]['sizes']['medium_large'] ?>
<?php echo $fore[0]['sizes']['medium_large'] ?>
```

Выводы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит только картинку из группы gallery1, а gallery2->card_gallery просто игнорирует, хотя gallery2->color и gallery2->text выводит правильно.
Подскажите, где может быть ошибка.

Comment: Вардампьте что там у Вас во второй группе, включите отладку и так далее. Не исключено, что в галереи для второй группы для изображений Вы возвращаете ID атачмента, а не массив, как вариант. Очень сомнительно что это баг именно в ACF PRO.